# Room 2.6.1 incorrect self-join

Tags: android, android-room

The documentation says:

> If the @Relation annotation does not meet your specific use case, you might need to use the JOIN keyword in your SQL queries to manually define the appropriate relationships. To learn more about querying multiple tables manually, read Accessing data using Room DAOs.

This my case. It's working if the tables are different, but if it's a self join, I'm getting an error.

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "table", primaryKeys = ["id", "qTypeId"]
)
data class Answer(
    val id: UUID,
    val qTypeId: UUID,
    val parentId: UUID?
...
)

@Query(
        """SELECT * FROM table AS PARENT
            LEFT JOIN table AS CHILD
            ON PARENT.id = CHILD.parent_id AND PARENT.qTypeId = CHILD.qTypeId
            WHERE PARENT.qTypeId =:qTypeId
                 """
    )
fun answerWithAnswers(qTypeId: UUID): Map<Answer, List<Answer>>
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method androidx.room.util.UUIDUtil.convertByteToUUID, parameter bytes

This error occurs when a LEFT JOIN is used. If you use a JOIN (not a LEFT JOIN) in a query, no error will occur, but an incorrect result will be obtained. It’s counterintuitive if you use syntax without the JOIN keyword to join a table to itself. (Use only WHERE)

Answer (score 0):

This is should be expected that is the LEFT JOIN is different to just a JOIN/Natural JOIN as per:-

> If there is an ON clause then the ON expression is evaluated for each row of the cartesian product as a boolean expression. Only rows for which the expression evaluates to true are included from the dataset.

versus:-

> If the join-operator is a "LEFT JOIN" or "LEFT OUTER JOIN", then after the ON or USING filtering clauses have been applied, an extra row is added to the output for each row in the original left-hand input dataset that does not match any row in the right-hand dataset. **The added rows contain NULL values in the columns that would normally contain values copied from the right-hand input dataset.**

https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#determination_of_input_data_from_clause_processing_

So if the result is the latter then the potential null values have to be handled and or discarded, perhaps via appropriate selection of result values.

For example perhaps:-

```
@Query(
        """SELECT PARENT.* FROM table AS PARENT
            LEFT JOIN table AS CHILD
            ON PARENT.id = CHILD.parent_id AND PARENT.qTypeId = CHILD.qTypeId
            WHERE PARENT.qTypeId =:qTypeId
                 """
    )
fun answerWithAnswers(qTypeId: UUID): Map<Answer, List<Answer>>
```

- i.e. ONLY the potentially null columns have not been extracted.

An alternative could be to ensure that NULLs are not NULLs e.g. you could use something like:-

```
SELECT parent.*,coalesce(child.id,-99),coalesce(child.qtypeid,-98),coalesce(child.parentid,-97) FROM table AS PARENT
            LEFT JOIN table AS CHILD
            ON PARENT.id = CHILD.parentid AND PARENT.qTypeId = CHILD.qTypeId
            WHERE PARENT.qTypeId =1
;
```

- noting that using table as the table name WILL result in syntax errors unless suitably enclosed.
- you may, if using this approach, also want to rename the output columns by adding an `AS` clause to the duplicated output column names.

Another option could be to handle the processing of the result via a function with a body and a rawQuery so that the resultant Cursor can be traversed.